# How to access a numeric property?

Tags: javascript

I have an object like:

```
var myObject = { '0' : 'blue' };
```

Now, when I try to access the value of the key '0' like:

```
myObject.0
```

...I am getting an error. (Maybe this is not the proper way?)

How can I access the value of a key that is a number (like the above)?

Comment: By the way, that isn't a JSON object—it's a *JavaScript* object. JSON is simply a data storage format that's based on JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This should work:

```
myObject["0"]
```

(`myObject["propertyName"]` is an alternative syntax for `myObject.propertyName`.)

You're getting the error because, in JavaScript, identifiers can't begin with a numeral. From the [Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Variables#Variables) page at the [Mozilla Developer Centre](https://developer.mozilla.org/):

> A JavaScript identifier must start
>   with a letter, underscore (_), or
>   dollar sign ($); subsequent characters
>   can also be digits (0-9). Because
>   JavaScript is case sensitive, letters
>   include the characters "A" through "Z"
>   (uppercase) and the characters "a"
>   through "z" (lowercase).

Comment: Properties *can* begin with a number. It's just that the "." syntax allows only identifers after the dot.

Comment: @Alsciende: Ah, thanks! I've corrected the relevant information in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

`myObject["0"]`

Answer (score 1):

if you have data like

```
  `"rain": {
           "3h": 0
         },`
```

then you can simply access it `rain['3h']`