# Javascript object erroring in IE8

Tags: javascript

```
    stages = {
            "1": {
                id: "1",
                div: "foo"
            },
            "2": {
                id: "2",
                div: "bar"
            },
            "3": {
                id: "3",
                div: "foobar"
            }
        };
```

When I run this in Firefox, it's fine.  But when run in IE8, I get this error:

> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method

Is this a known bug / is there a workaround or is it my syntax?

Comment: Have you tried declaring "stages" with `var` ?

Comment: No because I want it to be global

Comment: I've run the above in IE8 and didn't get an error. Perhaps you just need to wrap you key parts (id, div) in "" as well?

Comment: [And the line number is??](http://images.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/10617595.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't coming from a different part of your code?

Comment: It's possible that IE is hiccuping on the use of a number as a property, try `stage1`, ... instead.

Comment: I think @Abe Miessler might be right, I've tried this in Jsfiddle and it seems to work on its own.  It's just IE8 saying this line.

Comment: Also, are you using `with` anywhere in the code? That can affect this kind of scoping.  If you want to assign as a global variable `window.stages` would be more reliable.

Comment: Well actually keys of the object can't begin with a number. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026741/json-numeric-key

Comment: dfsq - that link states that properties can begin with a number. It is just that you cannot use the "." notation to address that key. You have to use stages["1"] to address it. Identifiers cannot begin with a number so 1stages would be invalid but stages or stages1 would be valid.

Comment: @dfsq that is not true - so long as they're quoted, as they are here, numbers are fine as keys.

Comment: @jdborg if you want it to be global, declare it at the global level (with `var`) or write `window['stages'] = { .. };`

Comment: Yep, that's how I was calling it anyway (stages["1"])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an element with `id=stages` in your markup, some browsers create global variable `stages` as a reference to it. However, IE doesn't support overriding it without declaring it. If you want `stages` variable to be global, put `var stages;` to global scope or assign the object to `window.stages`.

Comment: Thanks man, that's what was wrong.  Renamed stages to stagesDict and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get that error at all.  I can define that very code in a javascript file or in the console and it works just fine.

I do see that error if I try and run the code from jsfiddle.net.  However the error is referring to code in Action.js and the following code

```
if (e && e.target.getParent().get('id') == 'm') {
```

It appears to be unhappy with `e.target`.

How exactly are you causing that error to popup?