# How to read a json with a string "2012-12-13" as its key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access a numeric property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026741/how-to-access-a-numeric-property)

I write a page to access a api from other website.
it passes a json in the format of

```
{
    "a": {
        "2013-01-03": 3965,
        "total": 52284,
        "2013-01-05": 2636,
        "2013-01-04": 4086
    },
    "b": {
        "2013-01-03": 1969,
        "total": 25594,
        "2013-01-05": 1852,
        "2013-01-04": 2031
    },
    "c": {
        "2013-01-03": 6,
        "total": 443,
        "2013-01-05": 13,
        "2013-01-04": 19
    }
}
```

in my page, i try to access, for example data.a.total it will return 52284, but i cannot access data.a.2013-01-03, it will create an error. It seems that numbers cannot be the key for json. Can someone tell me whats the solution? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read it as `a['2012-12-13']` using the `[]` notation for accessing named properties.

For ex:

```
var data = {"a": {"2013-01-03": 3965, "total": 52284, "2013-01-05": 2636, "2013-01-04": 4086}, "b": {"2013-01-03": 1969, "total": 25594, "2013-01-05": 1852, "2013-01-04": 2031}, "c": {"2013-01-03": 6, "total": 443, "2013-01-05": 13, "2013-01-04": 19}};
```

`data.a['2013-01-03']` will give you `3965`

Answer (score 1):

Use the square bracket notation if the keys contain characters that are not valid as JavaScript identifiers:

```
json.a["2013-01-03"] // 3965
```