# In JavaScript, how do i address category with number as name?

Tags: javascript, html, json

[image]

i tried the following

```
document.getElementById("printnickname").innerHTML = myObject.data.503913138.nickname;
document.getElementById("printnickname").innerHTML = myObject.data[0].nickname;
document.getElementById("printnickname").innerHTML = myObject.data[1].nickname;
document.getElementById("printnickname").innerHTML = myObject.data."503913138".nickname;
```

none of which work.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552708/how-to-parse-json-with-number-as-a-key

Comment: Ok, i see it now. Javascript always converts numeric keys to string, so you have to use the array notation, instead of the dot one. Try the solution above.

Comment: thank you all for help. im sorry that i didnt see that this question had already been asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly the data structure, but maybe you could try

```
myObject.data["503913138"].nickname;
```

if data is an array and that number is a key of that array.

Comment: i keep trying, it says i can only accept in 4 minutes :)

Comment: You don't even need the quotes.