# How to retain datetime column in pandas grouper and group by?

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.8

I have a pandas dataframe that has a structure as shown in this question [Parsing JSON with number as key usng pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412513/parsing-json-with-number-as-key-usng-pandas)-

```
    Date       Time                 InverterVoltage        Invertercurrent
    2021-11-15 14:37:05              219.1                 20
    2021-11-15 14:38:05              210.2                 21
```

And so on . Data is available every 1 minute.

I have code like this -

```
df['inverterConsumption'] = df.inverterVoltage*df.inverterCurrent
```

Then I calculate the hourly mean by using this groupby construct

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(str)+' '+df['Time'].apply(str))
davg_df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='Datetime')).mean()
```

What I want to do is the following - I want to filter the inverterConsumption for only the month of September

```
davg_df2 = davg_df2[davg_df2['Datetime'].dt.month_name() =='September']
```

But I get an error saying

```
KeyError: Datetime
```

So clearly the `davg_df2` dataframe does not include the Datetime column that is present in `df`(as it is non numeric). How can I include that in the groupby and grouper clause ?

Pandas version 1.5.2 and Python version 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(str)+' '+df['Time'].apply(str))
davg_df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='Datetime')).mean().reset_index()
```

add reset_index() in result of groupby