# Unable to plot a pandas dataframe or calculate the median mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I have a similar problem to this question - [How to retain datetime column in pandas grouper and group by?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74920459/how-to-retain-datetime-column-in-pandas-grouper-and-group-by)

My data is like this -

```
 Date       Time                 Data1            Data2
 2021-11-15 1:00:05              100                 20
 2021-11-15 1:00:10              200                 21

 df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(str)+' '+df['Time'].apply(str))
 df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='Datetime')).mean().reset_index()
 df2 = df2[(df2['Datetime'] >'2022-09-16') & (df2['Datetime'] <'2022-10-01')
```

Then I try either of these constructs -

```
 df2.plot(x='Datetime',y='Data1')
 plt.show()
```

or

```
 a = pd.to_timedelta(df2['Datetime'] + ':00').mean()
```

In both these cases I get the following error

```
 KeyError: Datetime
```

Where am I going wrong ?

When I type

```
 df2.columns
```

`Datetime` is not one of the columns.

Based on the linked question and answer the datetime column should be part of the dataframe 'df2' but it is not happening in my case.
I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: What is the datatype of your `df["Datetime"]` column? What does `df.dtypes` give you?

Comment: @braml1The dtype of datetime is datetime64[ns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is going on, but the following code just seems to work. Make sure your data selection on `df2` includes the `pd.TimeStamp()` format though, instead of strings

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {"Date": ["2021-11-15", "2021-11-15", "2021-11-15", "2021-11-15"], 
        "Time": ["1:00:05", "1:00:10", "2:00:05", "2:00:10"],
        "Data1": [100,200,300,350],
        "Data2":[20,21,22,23]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(str)+' '+df['Time'].apply(str))
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='H', key='Datetime')).mean(numeric_only=True).reset_index()
df2 = df2[(df2['Datetime'] > pd.Timestamp('2020-03-31')) & (df2['Datetime'] <pd.Timestamp('2022-03-31'))]
 
df2.plot(x='Datetime',y='Data1')
plt.show()
```