# Referenceing a json object with an int

Tags: json, autocomplete

I have the following json (extract):

```
[{"series":{"series_long_name":"Micky mouse","id":"17684"},"0":{"listings":"3"}}]
```

I need to reference the number of listings to populate and autocomplete:

```
.data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {

        return $( "<li>" )
        .append( '<a>' + item.series.series_long_name + '<span class="listings-count">' + item.0.listings + '</span></a>' )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

but using item.0.listings throws an error, I guess because I can not add an int as an object key?

I believe that the 0 is being returned as it is a count().

Here is an extract array returned before being encoded:

```
(int) 0 => array(
        'series' => array(
            'series_long_name' => 'Micky mouse',
            'id' => '17684'
        ),
        (int) 0 => array(
            'listings' => '3'
        )
    ),
```

Any idea how best to tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use bracket notation to access the field. Ex: item[0] or item['0'].

See this answer for a more complete explanation: [How to access a numeric property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026741/how-to-access-a-numeric-property)