# Get value of numeric property from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object as shown below.

```
{
    "28903218": {
        "type": "group", 
        "prompt": "Cool, thanks! Now tell us about your child's day:", 
        "description": ""
    }, 
    "37742463": {
        "type": "choice", 
        "prompt": "How does {{answer_28903220}} react in an unwelcome situation?", 
        "description": "(Such as not wanting to be in the car seat, when you're not in the room at bedtime, etc.)"
    }, 
    "30035493": {
        "type": "choice", 
        "prompt": "Friday:", 
        "description": ""
    }, 
}
```

I have a problem to read it. How can I get the `28903218` property's value?

```
 surveyData.getQuestions().subscribe(
      result => {
        //here I need to get the "28903218" object's value 
      },
      err => { },
      () => { }
    );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a numeric property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026741/how-to-access-a-numeric-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you know `28903218`:

```
var value = result["28903218"];
```

If you don't know it then you could loop through the properties until you find the desired one:

```
for (var prop in result) {
    var value = result[prop];
}
```

Comment: @torazaburo, no idea, if you don't know what you are looking for, then how do you expect to find it? If you have no clues or patterns to identify it - then you are probably wasting your time :-) Normally when you are looking for something you know how it looks or at least how to identify it.