# How to get string element from an object

Tags: javascript, object

I have a variable that defines the integer.

Example:

```
var integer = x //11111, 222222, 333333, etc.
```

Then, I have an object:

```
Object { 111111: "string1", 222222: "string2", 333333: "string3", etc }
```

How to get a specific string element based on the integer variable I have?

Example:
If Selected Variable `22222` is how to get `string2`?

Comment: `yourobj[integer]`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP did no research at all.

Comment: if the object is in the y var you do y[222222] and you get the string2.

Comment: What have you tried? Otherwise what you have is a JavaScript object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a numeric property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026741/how-to-access-a-numeric-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it like this

```js
var object = { 111111: "string1", 222222: "string2", 333333: "string3"};
    
var string = object['222222'];

console.log(string)
```

Comment: He didn't tell that his code isn;t working, instead he was asking for a right code

Comment: Yes That is the point !!, if OP didn't provided any try we should not give solution, It shows laziness.

Comment: I tried. But I'm an absolute beginner. I failed to resolve on the basis of the existing questions and answers. Best

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use square bracket notation, as so:

```
const data = { 111111: "string1", 
              222222: "string2", 
              333333: "string3" };
let x = 111111;
console.log(data[x]);
```

Comment: Can you explain why his code is not working ? and why you did hree ?

Answer (score 1):

Pleaser refer this,

```
var integerVar = 222222;
var jsonObject = { "111111": "string1", "222222": "string2", "333333": "string3"}
console.log(jsonObject[integerVar]);
```

Comment: Can you explain why his code is not working ? and why you did hree ?