# Access a numeric property from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api

I am trying to access data from a api but the problem is that it has a numeric property name. 
This is how i access the data:

working:

```
data[i].price_usd
```

Not Working:

```
data[i].24h_volume_usd
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026741/how-to-access-a-numeric-property) solution but cant get it to work.

And also tried:

`var twentyfour_volume_usd = "24h_volume_usd";
data[i].twentyfour_volume_usd`

Comment: Can you share the JSON object as well?

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: If it's not a string than it's not [JSON](http://json.org)

Comment: yes i meant the data response. data[i]['24h_volume_usd'] worked as posted by @alf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `data[i]['24h_volume_usd']`.